# save multidimensional array with foreach loop in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I warite script to extract price and name from website with foreach loop.

```
foreach ($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;
    if ($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
        $data[] = array(
            $trip ['Name'] = trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
            $trip['LivePrice'] = trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
            $trip ['Changing'] = trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
            $trip ['Lowest'] = trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
            $trip['Topest'] = trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
            $trip['Time'] = trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue),
        );
    }
}
```

and then save they in to the database with mysql (no mysqli or pdo) . but only save one record ، If the 5 column provided .

and after each refresh the page save Previous record (i.e repetitive recod)

please see following .

in the database:

```
id | name | liveprice | changing | lowest | topest | time 
1  |  lg  |  25500    |   05     |  22500 |  22500 |  2014
2  |  lg  |  25500    |   05     |  22500 |  22500 |  2014
3  |  lg  |  25500    |   05     |  22500 |  22500 |  2014
```

database code and php for store data in to the database

```
$article = array();
mysql_select_db("coin", $con);

"CREATE TABLE `Dadoo`(id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(id),`title` VARCHAR(255),`liveprice` VARCHAR(255),`changing` VARCHAR(255),`lowest` VARCHAR(255),`topest` VARCHAR(255) ENGINE=MyISAM";

$debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Dadoo`(title,liveprice,changing,lowest,topest,time) VALUES ('" . $trip['Name'] . "','" . $trip['LivePrice'] . "','" . $trip['Changing'] . "','" . $trip['Lowest'] . "','" . $trip['Topest'] . "','" . $trip['Time'] . "')");

if (!$debugquery) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

now how can I save   multidimensional array  in the database?

Comment: You need to put the insert query inside the foreach loop, so it runs multiple times

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @ Oleg Dubas can you write example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your array needs to be outside the loop or you'll just be overwriting each index every time you loop:

```
$data = [];
$i = 0;
foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;
    if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
        $data[i]['Name' ] = trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $data[i]['LivePrice'] = trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue);
        $data[i]['Changing'] = trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue);
        $data[i]['Lowest'] = trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue);
        $data[i]['Topest'] = trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue);
        $data[i]['Time'] = trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue);

    }
}
```

you'll have to loop over your sql insert statement too. but the above code will at least leave you with an array containing more than one record.

-or-

the most efficient way might just be to generate the insert statement and perform the query inside your loop instead of storing the values in an array:

```
foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;
    if($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Dadoo`(title,liveprice,changing,lowest,topest,time) VALUES ('" . trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue) . "','" . trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue) . "')");
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,question : why don't save replace new records to Previous  records in the database?

Comment: An INSERT statement will always create a new row in your table. If you want to replace the records each time, you would need to UPDATE the row. [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with one query using the format:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, ...) 
VALUES (value01, value02, ...), (value11, value12, ...), ...
```

For example:

```
class InsertValues {

    private $values;
    private $row = array();

    public function endRow() {
        $this->values[] = '(' . implode(',', $this->row) . ')';
        $this->row = array();
    }

    public function addColumnValue($value, $quote = true) {
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($value)); //should use mysqli
        $this->row[] = $quote ? "'" . $value . "'" : $value;
    }

    public function render() {
        return implode(',', $this->values);
    }

}

mysql_select_db("coin", $con);

$inserValues = new InsertValues();

foreach ($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;
    if ($row->item(0)->tagName != 'tblhead') { // avoid headers
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(2)->nodeValue);
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(4)->nodeValue);
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(6)->nodeValue);
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(8)->nodeValue);
        $inserValues->addColumnValue($row->item(10)->nodeValue);

        //above can be replaced with a for loop ;)

        $inserValues->endRow();
    }
}

$debugquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Dadoo`(title,liveprice,changing,lowest,topest,time) "
        . "VALUES " . $inserValues->render());

if (!$debugquery) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```